# How to run a sql query in Cosmos DB where a particular key is having multiple values

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

[image]Below is the JSON file I have added in my CosmosDB :

```json
{
    "A": [
        "Uganda",
        "Vietnam",
        "Colombia",
        "Guatemala",
        "Paraguay",
        "Afghanistan",
        "India",
        "Iran",
        "Nepal",
        "Pakistan"
    ],
    "B": [
        "Bricks",
        "Bricks",
        "Bricks",
        "Broccoli",
        "Cabbages",
        "Carpets",
        "Carpets",
        "Carpets",
        "Carpets",
        "Carpets"
    ],
    "C": [
        "Child ",
        "Child ",
        "Child ",
        "Child ",
        "Child ",
        "Child ",
        "Child , Non Child",
        "Child",
        "Child , Non Child",
        "Child , Non Child"
    ]
```

When I am trying the following query :

```
SELECT *from tbl f WHERE f.Country = 'Uganda'
```

I am getting 0 results. I have the impression that a single key with multiple values in my JSON is causing the issue.

How can I process this JSON ?

Comment: Your JSON doesn't have any property called `Country`. That aside: Take a look at `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` (and the numerous questions and answers here directly related to searching within an array). This should help...

Comment: yes David ,I was looking into those options but somehow i have the impression there can be issue the way my json data is being present due to which it is unable to populate any data.

Comment: The issue with your JSON schema is that you have keys (such as `"A"` containing actual data. That is: what does `"A"` represent? If it's the value of something, then you should really consider refactoring your schema to be key:value (e.g. `{ "someKey" : "A", someValues: [...] } `. Otherwise there's really no way to enumerate all the values A, B, C, etc without knowing them in advance.

Comment: What do you get if you simply do ``SELECT * FROM c``?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that property `A` in your document is `Country`.

As David comments,`ARRAY_CONTAINS()` can do this,try this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.A,"Uganda")
```

Comment: I added the above query but still I am getting 0 results ,I have added a screen for the same above.

Comment: Please replace "A" to your real property in your document,maybe "Country".If  property "A" is a unknown key,you need to change schema like David says.